# Collision (shooting) in a game (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, collision-detection, collision

I am new to programming (day 3) and I spent the last two days trying to find out how to create the effect of shooting aka:

1. when the shoe touches the zombie, the zombie will flash and disappear
2. zombie will appear at the top again in a random fashion.

here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Rmva2/

I tried to use the collision plugins as well as following other people's code like: http://jsfiddle.net/98sAG/ but I am still quite confused.

Help will be super appreciated.

Thanks,
Agatha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprite based collision detection is hard in JavaScript, my suggestion would be to use a circular collision detection algorithm in JavaScript, because it is fast enough to use in real time games and the math is easy to understand. 
http://strd6.com/2010/06/circular-collision-detection-in-javascript/

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, so once I include that function, if the collision is true (aka shoes and zombie overlap) the explosion should be triggered? and return the zombie to the top?

thanks heavysixer :)

Comment: yes that's the way i'd handle it, because that is what the player would expect when a collision occurs.

Comment: hey Agg if this was an acceptable answer i'd appreciate if you accepted it. thanks!